# matlab find all cells containing each string in another cell array as fast as possible

Tags: arrays, string, matlab, cell

Imagine you have two cell arrays

`A={'a','b','b','c','d','e'}
B={'a','b','c','d','e','f'}`

and you want to (as fast as possible) obtain a cell of the indexes of the shared elements

e.g.

`{1,2,2,3,4,5}` the indexes in B for the elements of A

`{1,[2,3],4,5,6,[]}` the indexes in A for the elements of B

how would you do it?

Answer (score 1):

Here's how I would do it:

```
A = {'a','b','b','c','d','e'};
B = {'a','b','c','d','e','f'};
[~, ~, lab] = unique([A B]); % unique integer labels of elements in A and B
labA = lab(1:numel(A)); % this is A with each string replaced by its label
labB = lab(numel(A)+1:end); % this is B with each string replaced by its label
comp = bsxfun(@eq, labA(:), labB(:).'); % all pair-wise comparisons 
[ii, jj] = find(comp); % row and column indices of the matchings
result_AinB = accumarray(ii, jj, [numel(A) 1], @(x){sort(x(:).')}); % group jj by ii
result_BinA = accumarray(jj, ii, [numel(B) 1], @(x){sort(x(:).')}); % group ii by jj
```

This gives

```
>> celldisp(result_AinB)
result_AinB{1} =
     1
result_AinB{2} =
     2
result_AinB{3} =
     2
result_AinB{4} =
     3
result_AinB{5} =
     4
result_AinB{6} =
     5

>> celldisp(result_BinA)
result_BinA{1} =
     1
result_BinA{2} =
     2     3
result_BinA{3} =
     4
result_BinA{4} =
     5
result_BinA{5} =
     6
result_BinA{6} =
     []
```

Comment: That looks really good! However it seems not to work entierly when one cell array is much bigger than the other e.g.
 A = {'a','b','b','c','d','e'};
B = {'a','b','c','d','e','f','g','a','b','c','d','e','f','g'};

Comment: My cellfun version works with these larger arrays. :)

Comment: @Abijah Corrected. I had `numel(A)` and `numel(B)` mixed up

Answer (score 0):

Personally I would use

```
[c,ia,ib]=union(A,B)
```

or

```
[c,ia,ib]=intersect(A,B)
```

and handle the indices from these results. However this doesn't give the output in your requested format as it doesn't have the duplicates listed

```
ia = [1 2 3 4 5]
```

So to get it in your requested format use *ismember* twice.

```
Trial>> [~,ia]=ismember(A,B)

ia =

     1     2     2     3     4     5

Trial>> [~,ib]=ismember(B,A)

ib =

     1     2     4     5     6     0
```

Which is why I would use union or intersect as you can get all the required data from one call.

If you want it in that specific format then this should work

```
ia=cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(x,A)),B,'UniformOutput',false)
ib=cellfun(@(x) find(strcmp(x,B)),A,'UniformOutput',false)


ia =
  1×6 cell array
    [1]    [1×2 double]    [4]    [5]    [6]    [1×0 double]

ib =    
  1×6 cell array
    [1]    [2]    [2]    [3]    [4]    [5]
```

Comment: agreed not the precise results - but the exact formatting doesn't make sense to me and seems to be making it more complicated than it needs to be. I've updated my answer for completeness to include the cellfun option. This should give the desired result.